# Finding the worse-case runtime of a function

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I seriously do not understand where to go with the following question.

Any hints or steps would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I really want to know what I'm supposed to do, as opposed to just getting the answers.

I understand why we use Big-Oh (Worst-case) but I can't wrap my mind behind the mathematics. How to you calculate the total runtime?

Comment: Count, starting from the inner for loop, how many times each loop executes the operations inside it. What do you get?

Comment: You don't have any *worst* or *best* cases in the context. The sum of operations itself (let's assume the inmost loop as one operation) is equal to `n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6 == O(n**3)`.

Comment: @IVlad How do you count them if you have so many unknowns? _j:=i+1_ would be considered what?

Comment: How many times does `j` get incremented?

Comment: @IVlad If _i_'s max value is _n-1_, then _j_ would be _(n-1)+1_ = _n_, which means it is only incremented once? That wouldn't make any sense though. I'm really lost as to how to approach this.

Comment: How many times does `j` get incremented in terms of `n` and `i`?

Comment: @IVlad Would it be _n-i_ times?

Comment: Yes. So, the second `for` executes the third `n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` times. How many times does the third `for` execute its body in terms of `j`?

Comment: @IVlad _j_ times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Right. Now, for each of `j` iterating `n-1`, `n-2`, ..., `1` times, how many times will `k` iterate? Sum those, and you have the running time of the two inner loops.

Comment: @IVlad Would `k` iterate `j + (n-i) + (n-1)` times? I pulled `j` from the number of times the third loop ran, `(n-i)` from the number of times the second loop ran, and `(n-1)` from the number of times the first loop ran.

Comment: Ignore the first loop, so there is no `i`. You have the second running `n-1`. How many times will the third run? Then you have the second running `n-1`, how many times will the third run? Etc. until the second running `1`, how many times will the third run? Sum all these, what do you get?

Comment: @IVlad I'm a bit confused, but I think it'd be `j+(n-1)`, where `j` stems from the third loop, and `(n-1)` stems from the number of times the second loop runs.

Comment: You can't have `j` anymore either, it must be fully in terms of `n`.

Comment: @IVlad I can't really wrap my head around this. Could you give me a little hint?

Comment: `j = 2 => k iterates 2`, `j = 3 => 3, j = 4 => 4, ..., j = n => n`. `2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n = O(n^2)`. This is when `i = 1`. Now what happens when you consider the first for loop again?

Comment: @IVlad Kinda a guess, but would it be `n^2 * (n-1)` = `n^3 - n^2`?

Comment: Looks about right. You don't have to be exact, just have to find the dominating term. If you've found `n^3`, then the whole thing is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @IVlad Ohhhh, it's all clicking now. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate Big-Oh notation you need to find the worst case running time.
We do this for three loops

```
1) i varies from 1 to n-1  so total times the loop runs n-1=O(n)
2) j goes from 2 to n,3 to n..............n-1 to n so here total times the loop runs (n-2)+(n-3).......+1=(n-1)(n-2)/2=O(n^2)
3) now for each  value of j say a. k goes from 1 to a . This will add up another O(n) for each loop.(as value of a can go upto n)

Conclusion
Total loops of j O(n^2) and inside each loop we have O(n) operation.
Therefore O((n^2)*n)=O(n^3)
```

Hope i was able to explain how we get Big-Oh notation